# Secure login in zk

Tags: security, authentication, zk

I have a login with zk this is my login:

```
<zk>
<window id="Mnos" border="normal" width="320px"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('login.Login')">

    Username: <textbox value="@save(vm.username)"/>
    Password: <textbox value="@save(vm.password)" type="password" />
    <button label="submit" onClick="@command('login')" />

</window>
</zk>
```

And this is my model:

```
public class Login {

String username;
String password;

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}


@Command
@NotifyChange({"username", "password"})
public void login() {

    Users user = UsersDAO.getUserByEmail(username);
    if(user != null && md5function.MD5(password).equals(user.getPassword())){
            Executions.sendRedirect("/mainWindow.zul");
            Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("sessionUser", user.getIdUser());
            boolean role = false;
            if(user.getIdRole().getTypeRole().equals("ADMINISTRATOR")){
                role=true;
            }
            Sessions.getCurrent().setAttribute("sessionRole", role);
    }else
        Messagebox.show("email or password incorrect");
}


}
```

The problem is that i do not have a secure login, a user can go to another page without do the login.

My login only verify if the user and the password of the user exist in the database, and i do not know how can i integrate the security to my pages.

I have two roles:

```
Administrator
User
```

And i save a `sessionVariable` call: sessionRole with true if the user is administrator, but, and i have in my view in some tabs if the role is true: visible = true,  i do not know if it is well.

Somebody can help me?

I am reading:

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring%20Security/Add%20Page%20Based%20Security%20Using%20Authorized%20Roles

But i do not understand very well the configurations

And other examples use maven, and my project not use maven =S

Comment: You can use spring security framework to restrict the access to some pages by establishing filters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, just add a customized version of this to your config

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="Administrator" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.zul"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.zul?login_error=1" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home.zul"/>
</http>
```